# Excluir somente um registro no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Ao executar o código abaixo, mais de um registro é excluído do banco de dados. Não consigo encontrar o problema.

**Codigo para excluir**
*excluir_cliente.php*

```
<?php

require 'repositorio_clientes.php';

$clientes = $repositorio->getListarClientes();

echo"< br>< br>< br>< br>< br>< br>";

while($clienteTemporario = array_shift($clientes)){

if($clienteTemporario->getCodigo() == $_REQUEST['codigo']){

echo '<center>' . "Cliente: " . $clienteTemporario->getNome() . ", cpf: " . $clienteTemporario->getCpf() . $repositorio->excluirClientes($_REQUEST['codigo']) . "excluído com sucesso" . '</center>';

}

}

exit;

?>
```

**Página: repositorio_clientes.php**

```
<? php

require ' conexao.php ';

include 'cliente.php';

interface IRepositorioClientes {

public function cadastrarClientes($cliente);

public function excluirClientes($cliente);

public function atualizarClientes($cliente);

public function buscarCliente($codigo);

public function getListarClientes();

public function getListarClienteDia();

public function getListarClienteAtraso();

}

class RepositorioClientesMySQL implements IRepositorioClientes {

private $conexao;

public function __construct() {

$this->conexao = new Conexao("localhost", "root", "", "biblioteca");

if($this->conexao->conectar() == false) {

echo "Erro" . mysqli_error();

}

}

public function cadastrarClientes($cliente) {

$nome = $cliente->getNome();

$endereco = $cliente->getEndereco();

$cpf = $cliente->getCpf();

$saldo = $cliente->getSaldo();

$situacao = $cliente->getSituacao();

$data= $cliente->getData();

$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome, endereco, cpf, saldo, situacao, data) VALUES 
('$nome', '$endereco', '$cpf', '$saldo', '$situacao', '$data')";

$this->conexao->executarQuery($sql);

}

public function excluirClientes($codigo) {

$sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE codigo = '$codigo'";

$this->conexao->executarQuery($sql);

}

public function atualizarClientes($cliente) {

$nome = $cliente->getNome();

$codigo = $cliente->getCodigo();

$cpf = $cliente->getCpf();

$endereco = $cliente->getEndereco();

$saldo = $cliente->getSaldo();

$situacao = $cliente->getSituacao();

$data = $cliente->getData();

$linha = $this->conexao->obtemPrimeiroRegistroQuery;

$sql = "UPDATE cliente SET nome ='$nome', endereco='$endereco', cpf='$cpf', saldo='$saldo', situacao='$situacao', data='$data' WHERE codigo ='$codigo'";

$this->conexao->executarQuery($sql); 

}

public function buscarCliente($codigo) {

$linha = $this->conexao->obtemPrimeiroRegistroQuery ("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE codigo='$codigo'");

$cliente = new Cliente(

$linha['nome'],

$linha['codigo'],

$linha['endereco'],

$linha['cpf'],

$linha['saldo'],

$linha['situacao'],

$linha['data']); 

return $cliente; 

}

public function getListarClientes() {

$listagem = $this->conexao->executarQuery("SELECT * FROM cliente");

$arrayClientes = array();

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($listagem)){

    $cliente = new Cliente(

    $linha['nome'],

    $linha['codigo'],

    $linha['endereco'],

    $linha['cpf'],

    $linha['saldo'],

    $linha['situacao'],

    $linha['data']);

array_push($arrayClientes, $cliente);

}

return $arrayClientes;
}

public function getListarClienteDia() {

$listagem = $this->conexao->executarQuery("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE situacao='Em Dia'");

$arrayClientes = array();

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($listagem)){

    $cliente = new Cliente(

    $linha['nome'],

    $linha['codigo'],

    $linha['endereco'],

    $linha['cpf'],

    $linha['saldo'],

    $linha['situacao'],

    $linha['data']);

array_push($arrayClientes, $cliente);

}

return $arrayClientes;

}

public function getListarClienteAtraso() {

$listagem = $this->conexao->executarQuery("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE situacao='Em Atraso'");

$arrayClientes = array();

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($listagem)){

    $cliente = new Cliente(

    $linha['nome'],

    $linha['codigo'],

    $linha['endereco'],

    $linha['cpf'],

    $linha['saldo'],

    $linha['situacao'],

    $linha['data']);

array_push($arrayClientes, $cliente);

}

return $arrayClientes;

} 

}

$repositorio = new RepositorioClientesMySQL();

?>
```

Comment: Você precisa formular melhor sua questão, não coloque tudo na pergunta, seja objetivo e explique o que precisa no corpo da questão.

Comment: Ao excluir lembre de colocar um `WHERE` com o código do cliente.

Comment: @geysa o seu código `$repositorio->excluirClientes($_REQUEST['codigo'])` é um método apenas, precisamos do conteudo do `repositorio_clientes.php` para saber como este metodo funciona.

Comment: inseri o codigo da pagina repositorio_clientes.php

Comment: Não sei se tem algo a ver, mas quando estava corrigindo a citação do código vi que a abertura `<?php` estava com espaço, assim `< ?php`. Eu consertei isso pra formatação do código aparecer direito (colorido e tal), mas agora não sei se era o caso, por poder ser um problema do código né...

Comment: não é isso eu coloquei espaço no código para postar porque não estava pegando só como espaço mesmo, no meu trabalho não tem espaço ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se deseja apenas excluir um cliente informe o id/código não precisa de um while para isso.
Não é necessario usar php para verificar qual cliente da lista(array) da lista será removido, apenas passe o id para a função de deixe que o banco se encarregue dessa tarefa.

Pode simplificar:

```
while($clienteTemporario = array_shift($clientes)){
if($clienteTemporario->getCodigo() == $_REQUEST['codigo']){
   echo '<center>' . "Cliente: " . $clienteTemporario->getNome() . ", cpf: " .
   $clienteTemporario->getCpf() . $repositorio->excluirClientes($_REQUEST['codigo']) . 
   "excluído com sucesso" . '</center>';
}
```

Para:

```
if ($repositorio->excluirClientes($_REQUEST['codigo'])) {
   echo 'cliente excluido com sucesso';
} else {
   echo 'erro';
}
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mais da erro ao excluir.

Comment: Desculpa não tinha erro faltou atualiza a pagina...

Comment: mas continua excluindo todos os clientes cadastrados

Comment: Todos os clientes estão com o mesmo id?

Comment: sim, é este o problema? se for como faço para alterar o id?

Comment: Na sua tabela, se o banco for o mysql, no campo id/código defina ele como primary key e auto increment.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, agora está excluindo um por vez!

Comment: tenho outra dúvida, agora na listagem dos clientes.

Comment: @geysa, acredito que seja melhor criar uma nova pergunta descrevendo o problema, pode citar o link dessa pergunta caso seja relacionado.

Comment: Ok! irei fazer isto.

Comment: @geysa Se está resposta resolveu o teu problema, marque-a como correta. Se não entende como funciona o StackOverflow, faça um tour é bem rápido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour